# How to restart a pipeline when it is in playing state

Tags: state, gstreamer

I have a pipeline, which is in playing state,

```
GST_STATE_PLAYING
```

Now, after a while, when some certain condition met, i would like to restart the same pipeline.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the situation as stated [here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Trying-to-reset-the-pipeline-whithout-closing-it-td3814702.html)

You can put it into NULL and then PLAYING:

```
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
//do your stuff for example, change some elements, remove some elements etc:
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

Or you can just put it into READY(replace NULL with READY in above code) and set some parameters which should work I guess..

Regarding sync/async etc of the gst_element_set_state check docs [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstElement.html#gst-element-set-state)

Comment: but when i set the state to NULL, then the sink element changed from playing to paused and then blocked, i am not able to execute the next line of code, It is blocking at gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

Comment: @PrasanthKumarArisetti what happens when you first set to .._PAUSED and then _NULL? does the _PAUSED one block as well?

Comment: when i set the state to NULL in a call back function of a appsink, then it didn't work, but i separated the code to a separate timeout function, it working fine.

Comment: now, it is working, i used the state changes as you suggested, first NULL and the PLAYING.